# Browserify cannot find module has been installed from local filesystem

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, browserify, wasm-bindgen

I have several JavaScript files that requires several modules that are managed by NPM. I am trying to bundle these files together with Browserify. However, I am getting the following error:

`Cannot find module 'fairychess-web' from '...App.js'`

(the full path has been elided).

This module is required in the following area of App.js:

```js
    exports.__esModule = true;
    var jsx_runtime_1 = require("react/jsx-runtime");
    var react_1 = require("react");
    require("./App.css");
    var fairychess_web_1 = __importStar(require("fairychess-web"));
    var chess_lib_1 = require("./chess_lib");
    var net_lib_1 = require("./net_lib");
```

My dependencies are in my `package.json` file as follows:

```json
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^18.11.11",
        "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
        "fairychess-web": "file:../fairychess-web/pkg",
        "http": "^0.0.1-security",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "ws": "^8.11.0"
    }
```

As you can see, the offending `fairychess-web` module is defined locally rather than on the NPM registry. I think this is why Browserify is having trouble finding the module, because I'm not receiving any error messages about the previous imports of libraries downloaded from NPM, but I have no idea as to how to solve the problem.

## A few notes that may be relevant

- `App.js` and the rest of my files, like `chess_lib` and `net_lib`, were created though `tsc` run on TypeScript files.
- The `fairychess-web` module is a Rust package that was compiled to WASM with `wasm-bindgen`. This created a TypeScript wrapper file through which I am interfacing the Rust code and my Typescript code.
- This code was originally built on `create-react-app`. At that time there were no problems importing the local module, this problem only arose when I decided to manually build the project.